# Change the way nested views behave

Tags: views

In drupal 7 I have news posts grouped by the value of certain fields, I can filter them and display correctly the latest # news per category in a tabbed view: one tab per category. I also have another tab, which should collect the last news item from each category and I'm struggling to do it right.

I tried the nested views approach but despite creating a new template and new "helper" views with which I had hoped to strip all unnecessary tags, many tags are still created, breaking the layout (not really BREAKING, but it's not as it should).
Could someone suggest a way to strip the tags or (better!) to do this in one go?

I'm not a php/drupal dev but if assisted I can understand code.

**Update:**

I have narrowed down my problem to the fact that all items are rendered in one single row by the external view. This breaks the layout because there's no `</li><li...>` between them. Instead, they are wrapped by divs. I have worked on this but I don't know how to make them appear on separate rows and it seems all the remaining wrapping is created by the last `print $row` in the chain.
Can I change the behavior of the print or make the view display each field on a separate row?

Answer (score 0):

In the end the Semantic Views module helped me achieve what I wanted to do.

I specified that rows had no tag and fields instead were `<li>`, I had to modify the template too, for consistency and theming reasons to reproduce the original layout of a normal view.